# How to create new column (using dplyr's mutate) based on conditions applied on the entire piped dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I am looking of a way to create a new column (using dplyr's mutate) based on certain "conditions".

```
library(tidyverse)

qq <- 5

df <- data.frame(rn = 1:qq,
           a = rnorm(qq,0,1),
           b = rnorm(qq,10,5))

myf <- function(dataframe,value){
  result <- dataframe %>% 
    filter(rn<=value) %>% 
    nrow
  return(result)
}
```

The above example is a rather simplified version for which I am trying to filter the piped dataframe (df) and obtain a new column (foo) whose values will depict how many rows there are with rn less than or equal to the current rn (each row's rn - coming from the piped df ). Below you can see the output I am getting vs the one I expect to obtain :

```
df %>% 
  mutate(
    foo_i_am_getting = myf(.,rn),
    foo_expected = 1:qq)

         rn          a         b foo_i_am_getting foo_expected
1  1 -0.5403937 -4.945643                5            1
2  2  0.7169147  2.516924                5            2
3  3 -0.2610024 -7.003944                5            3
4  4 -0.9991419 -1.663043                5            4
5  5  1.4002610 15.501411                5            5
```

The actual calculation I am trying to perform is more cumbersome, however, if I solve the above simplified version, I believe I can handle the rest of the manipulation/calculations inside the custom function.

*BONUS QUESTION :* Currently the name of the column I want to apply the filter on (i.e. rn) is hardcoded in the custom function (***filter(rn<=value)***). It would be great if this was an argument of the custom function, to be passed 'tidyverse' style - i.e. *without quotation marks* - e.g. myf <- function(dataframe,rn,value)

Disclaimer : I 've done my best to describe the problem at hand, however, if there are still unclear spots please let me know so I can elaborate further.

Thanks in advance for your support!

Comment: It looks like your `foo_expected` should be `2,4,3,1,5`... is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it step by step, because now you are passing whole vector to filter instead of only one value each time:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(
    foo_i_am_getting = map_dbl(.$rn, function(x) nrow(filter(., rn <= x))),
    foo_expected = 1:qq)
```

Now we are passing 1 to filter for rn column (and function returns number of rows), then 2 for rn column.

Function could be:

```
myf <- function(vec_filter, dataframe, vec_rn) {
  map_dbl(vec_filter, ~ nrow(filter(dataframe, {{vec_rn}} <= .x)))
}

df %>% 
  mutate(
    foo_i_am_getting = map_dbl(.$rn, function(x) nrow(filter(., rn <= x))),
    foo_expected = 1:qq,
    foo_function = myf(rn, ., rn))
```

Comment: Seems to work great! Many thanks for the prompt response & explaining my mistake in the first place! Appreciate it